# How to remove <string> tag in web service return xml c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a web service that return a xml format..

But now the return is not well-formed xml, which is not hierarchical..

Here is a screenshot of the return xml:

[image: false return]

But, I want something like more  human-readable xml, which is hierarchically..

So, I tried to get the xml return without the `<string>` tag, which can display like I want..

Something like this:

[image: true xml]

I tried to remove the `<string>` tag on my code..

I just comment this code:

```
//[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
```

But the `<string>` tag always display on it (like first image)..

Anyone know how to remove it?

Thank You!

Comment: Where is the actual code where you commented WebService out, show relevant part of code.

Answer (score 1):

if you wont to view XML without string tag add XElement type in your method like this:

```
 [Web Method]
 public XElement Test(string XML){
 return XElement. Parse();
 }
```